# How do I compare objects pointing to a different place in memory?

Tags: ruby, object, comparison

I have an array of objects:

```
array = [ Obj1, Obj2, Obj3 ]
```

If I query `Obj1` from the `Objects` table:

```
obj1 = Objects.get(1)
```

Both `Obj1` and `obj1` are the same objects, but when I compare them I get `false`:

```
array[0].eql? obj1 # false
```

What's the best way to compare two objects when they are not pointing at the same place in memory?

Comment: what kind of objects they are ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, can be an object of type `Car`

Comment: What is .get?  I can't seem to find it in the [core documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html)

Comment: Seems like there's an ORM involved, is it [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/)?

Comment: Yes, there is an ORM involved.

Comment: @stsd, You're making those trying to help you dig out the information. It'd help if you were forthcoming with detail about your question. See http://sscce.org/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist and http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: So I would hypothesize that the .get function is returning a copy of the object, and not a reference, so that the two variables are not actually pointing at the same object.  If this is the case, then @Charizard_'s answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for these kinds of comparisons of the value possessed by these same types of objects, you need to define your own comparison operator like `<=>` or whatever sign you like, but don't override default operators like `==`. That may lead to a problem.

See "[Ruby Equality And Object Comparison](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/)."